# Display scale line - ArcGIS Runtime SDK - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, arcgis-runtime-net

I am using the 1st release of the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .Net - Xamarin.Forms (nuget package [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Xamarin.Forms/100.0.0)).

One of my requirements is to display a basic scale line on the map. I haven't found any build-in feature for the moment. 
It seems to be tricky because each device has different size, different resolution... Any idea on how to implement this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK after few hours, I found that the `MapView` component has a property `UnitsPerPixel` that do exactly what I needed:

I've added a small grid (to represent the scale) with a fix width:

```
<Grid  HeightRequest="10" WidthRequest="114" x:Name="Legend">
...
</Grid>
```

Then when the view point changes, I compute the distance representing by this grid:

```
MapView.ViewpointChanged += (sender, args) =>
{
    ScaleVal.Text = $"{Math.Round(Legend.Width * MapView.UnitsPerPixel, 0)}m";
};
```

[image: ArcGIS .Net SDK - Xamarin.Forms - Scale Line]

Complete solution [here](https://github.com/CrazyTuna/arcgis-runtime-xamarin-toolkit).